# Extract variable labels from rpart decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I've used part to build a decision tree on a dataset that has categorical variables with hundreds of levels.  The tree splits these variables based on select values of the variable.  I would like to examine the labels on which the split is made.

If I just run the decision tree result, the display listing the splits in the console gets truncated and either way, it is not in an easily-interpretable format (separated by commas).  Is there a way to access this as an R object?  I'm open to using another package to build the tree.

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd start by searching through the results of `str(myTree)`.

Comment: There is almost certainly a way to get at the information which is being printed in truncated form. Looking at the manual is probably a good way to find out how.

Comment: try the `rpart.plot` package

Comment: `rpart.utils` package, function `rpart.subrules.table` will help you out

Answer (score 3):

One issue here is that some of the functions in the `rpart` package are not exported. It appears you're looking to capture the output of the function `rpart:::print.rpart`. So, beginning with a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(y=rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.5),
                  x1=rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.25),
                  x2=rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.75))
(r1 <- rpart(y ~ ., data=df1))
```

giving

```
n= 100 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 100 24.960000 0.4800000  
  2) x1< 0.5 78 19.179490 0.4358974  
    4) x2>=0.5 66 15.954550 0.4090909 *
    5) x2< 0.5 12  2.916667 0.5833333 *
  3) x1>=0.5 22  5.090909 0.6363636  
    6) x2< 0.5 7  1.714286 0.4285714 *
    7) x2>=0.5 15  2.933333 0.7333333 *
```

Now, looking at `rpart:::print.rpart`, we see a call to `rpart:::labels.rpart`, giving us the splits (or names of the 'rows' in the output above). The value of `n, deviance, yval` and more are stored in `r1$frame`, which can be seen by inspecting the output from `unclass(r1)`.

Thus we could extract the above with

```
(df2 <- data.frame(split=rpart:::labels.rpart(r1), n=r1$frame$n))
```

giving

```
    split   n
1    root 100
2 x1< 0.5  78
3 x2>=0.5  66
4 x2< 0.5  12
5 x1>=0.5  22
6 x2< 0.5   7
7 x2>=0.5  15
```

Comment: great answer! can you please take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679523/r-obtaining-rules-from-a-function ? thanks!